# Ionic how to hide ionicActionSheet menu after tap on hardware back button on device?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, back-button

in my Ionic app after tap on list item displaying Action sheet menu:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicActionSheet/

I would like to hide displayed action sheet menu after tap on hardware back button on Android device. Is it possible? And if yes and how can i do it please?

Thanks for any help.

**Code which displaying action sheet menu:**

```
$scope.showActionMenu = function(number,id,itemIndex) {
            // Show the action sheet
            var hideSheet = $ionicActionSheet.show({
                titleText: 'Select action',
                buttons: [
                    { text: 'Call' }
                ],
                destructiveText: 'Delete',
                cancelText: 'Cancel',
                cancel: function() {
                    hideSheet();
                },
                destructiveButtonClicked: function() {
                    console.log(id);
                    console.log(itemIndex);
                    $scope.deletePlannedCall(id,itemIndex);
                    return true;
                },
                buttonClicked: function(index) {
                    console.log(number);
                    $scope.callTo(number);
                    return true;
                }
            });

        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
onHardwareBackButton(callback)
```

of  `$ionicPlatform` (docs in http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/)

using as callback the hide function.